# VARCHAR Field Returning Scientific Notation

Tags: mysql

I am trying a SELECT statement that pulls back data with latitude and longitude information.   But when the longitude is returned, it is in scientific notation.

What is the best way to do this?   Right now, the Longitude field is VARCHAR(15).

I am populating the table from raw data.  I have tried formatting the longitude field from VARCHAR(15) to DECIMAL(15,7).   When I do that, I have trouble populating the table with the LOAD DATA INFILE command.

I have tried formatting the longitude numbers both as numbers and as text (with " around them).  The file has to be tab delimited and not CSV.

Example of the raw data:

```
"ANCHORAGE" "AK"    "99505" ""  "61.2775000"    -149.6436000    
or 
"ANCHORAGE" "AK"    "99505" ""  "61.2775000"    "-149.6436000"
```

"SELECT * FROM Table" returns -1..4964E+9 for the Longitude.

The Latitude comes back correct with the Latitude field as VARCHAR(15).  So I am thinking it has something to do with the Longitude being negative.

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: We use datatype `DECIMAL(10,6)` for latitude and longitude values. Six decimal places gets us resolution within a meter, which is precise enough for our purpose. (We don't really need more than three digits before the decimal point, but with decimal datatype, we get two digits per byte, so `(10,6)` is the same number of bytes as `(9,6)`. The approach I would take is figure out what the problem is with the LOAD DATA. I'd use a user-defined variable in the field list, and reference the actual column in the SET clause, ...

Comment: If the column `col` is defined as datatype VARCHAR(15) , then `SELECT col` query will return the characters that are stored.  If it looks like scientific notation  then that's the characters that got stored. It's not a problem with the query, the problem is with the data that is stored. The question says "tried formatting... from VARCHAR(15) to DECIMAL.. "  this would be more accurately described as a modification of the *datatype*. This isn't just *format*.  There are lots of ways to get MySQL to perform datatype conversions, implicit and explicit `CAST()`, `CONVERT()`, the `+ 0` trick, et al

Comment: Keep in mind how [ridiculous seven places of precision](https://xkcd.com/2170/) is for GIS data.

Comment: Much thanks.  Going back to the raw data and see if I can get it the way I need.

Comment: But I may need to find Waldo in Alaska!   Point taken.  Thanks.